# Active Directory: need to authenticate and get the user details in c#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am connecting to AD and checking the username exists and validating the credentials in my local machine and it is working fine.

```
bool userAuthenticated = false;
var domainName = DomainName;

if (useSSL)
{
    domainName = domainName + ":636";
    ContextOptions options = ContextOptions.SimpleBind | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer;

    using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, null, options, domainuser, domainpassword))
    {
        userAuthenticated = pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password, options);
    }
}
else
{
    using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
    {
        userAuthenticated = pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
    }
}

return userAuthenticated;
```

But when the code is deployed in the server it is throwing an error

> Invalid username / password

But our team is providing only GMSA account and it is not having the password.

How do I authenticate the credentials and check the username in AD exists or not?